# SVG Element Overlapping Even with Correct x and y

Tags: html, css, svg

I am showing some `textbox` in `svg` one after other and they are positioned by their `x` and `y` attributes values. The code is given below.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="-6 -6 512 312">
   <g>
      <path d="M15,0h470a15,15 0 0 1 15,15v270a15,15 0 0 1 -15,15h-470a15,15 0 0 1 -15,-15v-270a15,15 0 0 1 15,-15z" id="stroke-path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12"></path>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(127, 49, 47);" text-anchor="start" x="60.4056510925293" y="128.50210571289062">1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</text>
      <title>1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(1, 138, 128);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="162.99429321289062">Earliest Date Time End</text>
      <title>Earliest Date Time End</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(253, 98, 94);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="128.50210571289062">Hello</text>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(254, 150, 102);" text-anchor="start" x="381.7397880554199" y="128.50210571289062">dfsdf</text>
      <title>dfsdf</title>
   </g>
</svg>
```

If you run above code snippet you will see that text **dfsdf** is overlapping on date.
The `x` value of text **dfsdf** is calculated as below.

**x** = **10**(x of Hello) + **50.41**(width of Hello) + **321.33**(width of date) = **381.74**

By above calculation it should not overlap with date. but still it is overlapping. How do I make sure that it does not overlap on date?

Please note that the width of this text elements are dynamic and I am getting this width by using `getBoundingClientRect` function in javascript.

Comment: If you remove the white space gaps between the date string, the widths line up well and no overlapping occurs. I don't understand what's really going on, though! So frustrating.

Comment: I think the calculated width of date is including whitespace inisde date because when I remove the space, it also reduces width to 302

Comment: Your viewBox units are no longer pixels, so a measurement using ClientRect (which return pixel values) won't match the SVG unit system anymore. This could be at least part of it.

Comment: @MichaelMullany So what will be the correct approach here? Is there a method to calculate it properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a little bit of javascript to calculate the position of every text using the `getComputedTextLength()` method.

```js
let h = hello.getComputedTextLength();

time.setAttributeNS(null,"x", 10 + h + 20 )

let t = time.getComputedTextLength();

dfsdf.setAttributeNS(null,"x", 10 + h + 20 + t + 20 )
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="-6 -6 512 312">
   <g>
      <path d="M15,0h470a15,15 0 0 1 15,15v270a15,15 0 0 1 -15,15h-470a15,15 0 0 1 -15,-15v-270a15,15 0 0 1 15,-15z" id="stroke-path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12"></path>
   </g>
  <g>
      <text id="hello" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(253, 98, 94);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="128.50210571289062">Hello</text>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </g>
  <g>
      <text id="dfsdf" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(254, 150, 102);" text-anchor="start" x="381.7397880554199" y="128.50210571289062">dfsdf</text>
      <title>dfsdf</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text id="time" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(127, 49, 47);" text-anchor="start" x="60.4056510925293" y="128.50210571289062">1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</text>
      <title>1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(1, 138, 128);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="162.99429321289062">Earliest Date Time End</text>
      <title>Earliest Date Time End</title>
   </g>

</svg>
```

An alternative solution would be positioning the text like this:

**Hello**: `text-anchor="start" x="10"`

**dfsdf**: `text-anchor="end" x="490"`

**time**: `text-anchor="middle" x="250"`

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="-6 -6 512 312">
   <g>
      <path d="M15,0h470a15,15 0 0 1 15,15v270a15,15 0 0 1 -15,15h-470a15,15 0 0 1 -15,-15v-270a15,15 0 0 1 15,-15z" id="stroke-path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="12"></path>
   </g>
  <g>
      <text id="hello" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(253, 98, 94);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="128.50210571289062">Hello</text>
      <title>Hello</title>
   </g>
  <g>
      <text id="dfsdf" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22.6667px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(254, 150, 102);" text-anchor="end" x="490" y="128.50210571289062">dfsdf</text>
      <title>dfsdf</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text id="time" alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 36px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(127, 49, 47);" text-anchor="middle" x="250" y="128.50210571289062">1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</text>
      <title>1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM</title>
   </g>
   <g>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" style="font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; fill: rgb(1, 138, 128);" text-anchor="start" x="10" y="162.99429321289062">Earliest Date Time End</text>
      <title>Earliest Date Time End</title>
   </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: In your first example you are adding 20px constant spacing between them. But what I am trying to do is just based on dynamic width of this text elements. I am using `getBoundingClientRect` function in javascript to get width of group elements.

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand your comment. You can easily remove the 20units or change it to a different value.  I'm using `getComputedTextLength()` to get the length of text and the result is the same as the one I would get with `getBBox()`. Do not use `getBoundingClientRect `

Comment: I have use `getBoundingClientRect` because `getBBox` is not supported in IE